# How to use kotlinx serialization with Spring AMQP?

Tags: jackson, spring-amqp, kotlinx.serialization

It seems that [spring AMQP](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp) has built-in `MessageConverter` support for Jackson with the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` class, but is there an equivalent for the [kotlinx serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) lib, or would it be necessary to write a custom message converter for it?

Trying to deserialize a JSON AMQP message without providing a MessageConverter Bean will cause an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to write your own `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter` implementation for Kotlin Serialization.

It looks like we can borrow ideas from the `org.springframework.messaging.converter.KotlinSerializationJsonMessageConverter`.

However you also can use a `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter` with a delegate to the mentioned `KotlinSerializationJsonMessageConverter`.

See `AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setMessageConverter(MessageConverter messageConverter)`.